# Joomla admin log in denied

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, administration

I moved my site from wordpress to Joomla. I created account and was working fine. I tried to log into admin few days later but now my credentials arent being accepted. tried retrieving username and password but the it says my email is not registered. Tried every email i have just incase but still no luck. Tried searching on Joomla site to find some kind of support service. But no luck either. I have been searching on forums for 2 days for help. still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried [How do you recover or reset your admin password? - Joomla! Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F)

Comment: Hi Stephen. That is really helpful thank you. I will go and see where that is located and why I couldn't find it. I actually got lucky while starting another project and remembered my user name suddenly. But I do really appreciate you answering my question. Have a good weekend